# How do I install SQL Svr Native Client 10.1 after SQL 2012 has been installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2012

On a Windows Server 2012 I have SQL Server 2012 installed which has the SQL Server Native Client version 11.  I am being told by a developer that he needs the SQL Server Native Client version 10.1 (SQLNCLI10.1).

I downloaded a native client sqlncli.msi but received the message 'Installation of SQL Server 2008 Native Client failed because a higher version already exists on the machine...'  Is there another download to install or is there a way to copy certain files from a server already containing the desired Native Client and then performing the registration without doing a complete reinstallation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [**this post**](http://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/archive/2013/04/05/installing-sql-server-native-client-10-0.aspx) which tells of a similar situation.  The author used the SQL Native Client .msi from the `\x64\Setup\x64 folder` of the SQL 2008 distribution media.  Maybe that will do it.

If not, you should be ok to uninstall the SQL Native Client 11, install v10 and then reinstall 11.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't access the distribution media, the installer for "SQL Server Native Client version 10.0" can be downloaded from the [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16978). Expand the "Install Instructions" and search for "2008 R2 Native Client".

Answer (score 3):

this is the link to SQL Native Client 10.0 (2008 R2) x64
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188401&clcid=0x409

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks. Most useful answer on the page for me. @AndrewSchulman - It's a download link to the installer. Of course the contents of this binary can't be included in the answer.

Comment: very nice. hard to find the direct link to that download.

Comment: Link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

**The First Answer From Sqillman (https://serverfault.com/a/506567/173328) works! Kudos!**

Here's what it solved for us...

For us, the answer (above/below?) allows access to SQL Server 2000 databases from SQL Server 2012 Integration Services packages that are hosted on a SQL Server 2012 database server running on Windows Server 2012 OS. We followed these suggestions to install SQLNCLI10 on our 2012 database server.  Our problem occured because the hosting db server never had the old SQL 2008 "SQLNCLI10" installed. That is, it never had SQL Server 2008 installed or an older OS.

The SSIS server error that started our research was: "The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered"

It is worth noting that when following the solution from squillman/technet/etc, while installing the 2008 SQLNCLI.msi on one of our new servers, we received the error "Installation of SQL Server 2008 failed because a higher version already exists on the machine...." Despite this, the driver was installed and worked properly without hurting 2012 db server functionality.  It installed alongside the existing 2012 SQLNCLI11 driver nicely.

In SSIS 2012, our packages use an "OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 10.0" connection to access the SQL Server 2000 databases (we actually just edited the connection strings and changed Provider from "SQLNCLI11.1" to "SQLNCLI10.1").  The developers had both drivers on their machines and so did the db servers we originally deployed to.  It was only when the final "Pure" 2012 servers were built out that the old driver disappeared and packages failed.

Note: In connection strings, "Provider = SQLNCLI10.1" is a synonym for "Provider = SQLNCLI10".  they both use the same dll.

-Patrick Hayes, Stefanini